# How can I show/hide <li> on check radio using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

How can I show/hide li classes on check/unchecked radio buttons?

I'd done it through code behind, but I want it through JavaScript or jQuery, if I remove `runat="server"` from input radio it works fine but I have some forms in li classes so when I press submit/save its saved and return to 1st tab. If I remove `checked="checked"`, on first loading doesn't show any tab.

```
<div class="pcss3t" >
<input type="radio" name="pcss3t" id="tab1" checked runat="server" class="tab-content-1"/>
<label for="tab1">Property</label>                  
<input type="radio" name="pcss3t" id="tab2" runat="server" class="tab-content-2" />
<label for="tab2">Allottee</label>                    
<input type="radio" name="pcss3t" id="tab3" runat="server" class="tab-content-3" />
<label for="tab3">Transferee</label>

<ul>

<li class="tab-content tab-content-1" id="tabcontent1" runat="server">
<table></table>
</li>

<li class="tab-content tab-content-2" id="tabcontent2" runat="server">
    <table></table>
</li>

<li class="tab-content tab-content-3" id="tabcontent3" runat="server">
    <table></table>
</li>

</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to understand you well, You want to show or hide a list item based on the checkbox selected.

First Hide them all using

```
$('.tab-content').hide();
```

then add a 'on change' event handler to the checkboxes. for that add a common class to all the radio buttons, lets say 'radioButton' then bind the handler 
like this:

```
$(".radioButton").change(function() {
       $('.tab-content').hide()
       $('#'+this.dataset.show).show()
})
```

and then update your html to have the data attribute and the class name

```
<div class="pcss3t" >
    <input type="radio" name="pcss3t" id="tab1" data-show="tabcontent1" class="radioButton"/>
    <label for="tab1">Property</label>                  
    <input type="radio" name="pcss3t" id="tab2" data-show="tabcontent2" class="radioButton" />
    <label for="tab2" >Allottee</label>                    
    <input type="radio" name="pcss3t" id="tab3" data-show="tabcontent3" class="radioButton" />
    <label for="tab3">Transferee</label>
    <ul>
        <li class="tab-content tab-content-1" id="tabcontent1" runat="server">
        <table>1</table>
        </li>
        <li class="tab-content tab-content-2" id="tabcontent2" runat="server">
            <table>2</table>
        </li>
        <li class="tab-content tab-content-3" id="tabcontent3" runat="server">
            <table>3</table>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

here is a working jsfiddle  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/95f6pszu/).

Comment: Its not all working in my case.. may be my css affecting it.. here is my css..    css is too long to upload

Comment: .pcss3t{
margin-top:10px;
padding-top:10px;
border:0;
outline: none;
font-size: 0;
text-align: left;
}
.pcss3t > input {
position: absolute;
display: none;
}
.pcss3t > label {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
margin-right:1px;
border:0;
outline: none;
cursor: pointer;
transition: all 0.1s;
-o-transition: all 0.1s; 
-ms-transition: all 0.1s; 
-moz-transition: all 0.1s; 
-webkit-transition: all 0.1s;
padding: 0 20px;
background:#F2F2F2;
font-size: 13px;
line-height: 49px;
}

Comment: .pcss3t > label i {
display: block;
float: left;
margin: 0 8px 0 -2px;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
outline: none;
font-family: FontAwesome;
font-style: normal;
font-size: 17px;
}
.pcss3t > input:checked + label {
cursor: default;
background:#E5E5E5;
}
.pcss3t > label:hover
{
background:#D6D6D6;
}
.pcss3t > ul {
list-style: none;
position: relative;
display: block;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
outline: none;
font-size: 13px;
background: #fff;
text-align: left;
}

Comment: .pcss3t > ul > li {
position: absolute;
background:#E5E5E5;
width: 100%;
overflow:auto;
padding: 0px 40px 0px;
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
opacity: 0;
transition: all 0.5s;
-o-transition: all 0.5s; 
-ms-transition: all 0.5s; 
-moz-transition: all 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}

Comment: Ohh man.. you should have just updated the jsfiddle.. but thats alright I did it for you :). checkout the updated one [here](http://jsfiddle.net/95f6pszu/1/). Yes the issue was with the css, specifically the one where you are trying to animate the opacity. Instead, I just used the jquery FadeOut() and FadeIn(). Hope this help and if satisfied please mark this as answered :)

Comment: Thanks shakirthow.! its not working in my case, I've form data in tabs with save button, when i remove runat server tag from radio button it doesn't stay on the same tab(mean rechek radio by default  first one or when i remove checked="checked" from first radio it doesn't show any tab after save button click )

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#tab1").on("click", function() {
    $(".tab-content-1").toggle();
});
```